# nginx: [emerg] the duplicate "request_id" variable in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I read somewhere that this error "nginx: [emerg] the duplicate "request_id" variable in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
is due to me using a version of Nginx that does not support X-Rid-header module.

Has there been a fix for this maybe, as i dont want to drop below version 1.11.x

Thanks

Comment: I think both are doing the same thing! am i right ?

Comment: hi there, yes you are, there is no need to use x-rid-header anymore, as nginx now has $request_id function build in.

Answer (score 1):

`$request_id` is a newly added embedded predefined variable in ngx_core_http module, since version `1.11.0` [1]. If you previously defined it in older version and not rename or remove it after upgraded beyond 1.11.0, you will get that duplicate "request_id" variable error.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables